# Solving the Kepler Problem With Cartesian Coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems

if we look at the Lagrangian for the Kepler problem in cartesian coordinates, we obtain sth like

$$\mathcal L\left( \vec X, \vec x, \dot{\vec{X}}, \dot{\vec{x}} \right) = \frac{M}{2} \dot{\vec{X}}^2 + \frac{m}{2} \dot{\vec{x}}^2 + \frac{GMm}{\left| \vec x \right|},$$

where $\vec x$ describes the relative motion and $\vec X$ the motion of the center of mass.

$$ M=m_1+m_2, \qquad m = \frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1+m_2}. $$
Now, applying the Lagrange equations of the second kind, we obtain

$$M\ddot{\vec{X}} = 0 \\ m\ddot{\vec{x}} = \vec\nabla \left( \frac{GMm}{\left| \vec x \right|} \right) = -\frac{GMm}{\left|\vec x\right|^3}\vec{x}$$

Now, solving the equation for the center of mass is very easy, but can we actually solve the second differential equation in cartesian coordinates? Because if not, then I understand why we move to spherical coordinates for the Lagrangian, at least this is what my textbook does now.

Comment: Yes sure, solving the center of mass differential equation is trivial enough. But the center of mass motion is not our main concern, it is just some system with a center of mass moving with some velocity, but solving the differential equation of the relative coordinate is the not-so-easy-task. That's why we invoke conservation of angular momentum and all the other things that we can notice to reduce a 6-dimensional problem to merely a one-dimensional problem.

Comment: (Contd.)
As you will see, the differential equation in spherical coordinates (or actually, the polar coordinates) is easy enough and the spherical coordinates lagrangian actually makes one of the coordinates very clearly stand out as being cyclic.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but I'm afraid this does not really answer my question.. Is it possible to solve the equation $$m\ddot{\vec{x}} = -\frac{GMm}{\left| x \right|^3} \vec{x}$$ in cartesian coordinates? If so, I would also be interested in the HOW, but maybe these are two questions?

Comment: Your question seems to be of mathematical interest only so perhaps it should be on Mathematics SE. In the solution of differential equations tricks such as substitutions are common. Any mathematical solution will probably make substitutions which are equivalent to a transformation to polar co-ordinates in the centre-of-mass frame and conservation of angular momentum, even if it does not identify these physical concepts. You can always transform the spherical polar solution back into Cartesian co-ordinates if you wish.